# MongoDB sort by date, but with top results

Tags: mongodb

I have a paginated query looking like that one :

```
db.users.find( {
    'profile.categoryCodes': {
        $in: ...,
    },
    'profile.roles...': ...
}, {
    sort: {
        createdAt: -1
    },
    limit: 12,
    skip: 12 * ( page - 1 ),
    fields: {
        ...
    }
} )
```

I'd like to add manually some top users for each category. I could add a new field like `topPlayerForThatCategory: 1` and sort on that field too. But i'd like something easier to do, and add a list of ids somewhere that say : 'those players are in the top'.

Any idea ?

Comment: I am not sure I understand what you are asking. Do you want the top x users which were created at a given day? What is a "top user" in your database? I can't see a field like "score" or something in your example.

Comment: Yes, there is no such thing in my example. The goal is to have all the user sorted by creation date (they have a createdAt field). But to have always users 17, 281 and 3 on the top of this ranking. And I know those users by their mongo ID.